Jupyter hub custom authentication using token in header
I am using jupyter on my device mac ( apple silicon M2 ) which i cloned from the github repository what i want do is i will generate a generate a image and deploy on GKE for my users to use , now how my users are going to use it is they will be logged in on my onBording application once they are logged in they will have a redirect url that will rediect them to their jupyter notebook ( specific to user ) so in between what we want to do is create a auth service that will take then token from the redirect URL for the user which was generated by my application , by pass the jupyterhub login page ( running it as backend ) and whatever data i get inside this token will be given to the hub to generate api tokens for this user and than user will see his jupyternotebook ( lab works too ) on his frontend
now not all of my users are GCIP they will be identified by IAP on my GCP project and than a token will be generated which have have another token inside it with some user data
i tried various custom authenticator that will use the token and decode it but it seems there are not working

Jupyterhub Custom Authenticator
https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1546
https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/4445
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/can-i-auto-create-users-in-hub-auto-install-a-notebook-in-user-dir-and-auto-login-using-a-token/18935
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterhub-login-via-token/19369/4


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
